# Pulling duplicate rows/criteria not working?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a VBA newbie, pretty much learning by modifying existing macros and trial and error, so I apologize if what I am asking seems bush-league.

I combined/modified some macros to pull rows from an external workbook onto my workbook based on criteria. The issue is that I am randomly being given duplicate rows, and I cannot figure out as to why. Can anyone see what the issue is? The second issue I am having is that in addition to the column AF criteria, I would like to filter so that the dates in column E fall between the dates specified in two cells on a different sheet.

I have been trying to use the line:

```
If DateValue.Sheets("Control")("B1") < ("E1:E" & B) < DateValue.Sheets("Control")("C1") Then
```

but I am either placing it incorrectly or just completely off on the coding... Can someone help me out with that?

```
Sub FetchComplaints()
Dim path            As String
Dim FileName        As String
Dim LastCell        As Range
Dim Wkb             As Workbook
Dim WS              As Worksheet
Dim ThisWB          As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:S1000").Clear
Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Activate
Range("A1:AP5000").Clear
ThisWB = ThisWorkbook.Name
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
path = GetFileName

        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
            WS.Select
            B = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
            If B = 0 Then
                            Else
                For Each cell In Range("AF1:A" & B)
                If cell.Value = True Or cell.Value = "Written" Then
                Anum =  Application.CountA(Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A:A")) + 1
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Workbooks(ThisWB).Sheets("ComplaintsFetched").Range("A" & Anum)
               End If
               Next cell
            End If
        Next WS
        Wkb.Close False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Wkb = Nothing
Set LastCell = Nothing

Set LastCell = Nothing
```

GetFileName is a function which retrieves the path.

Thanks for any help, and sorry if I am missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this syntax:

```
If Sheets("Control").Range("B1").Value < Sheets("Control").Range("C" & B).Value ...
```

Multiple conditions should be combined using `And`.

Comment: I'm sorry I've never attempted anything this in depth in vba. I am not sure where I would enter the line:
`If Sheets("Control").Range("B1").Value < Sheets("Control").Range("E" & B).Value and Sheets("Control").Range("C1").Value > Sheets("Control").Range("E" & B).Value`

Comment: @user1872838 This code will return TRUE if both B1 and C1 values are less than E[B-number] value. Further depends on your actual needs.

Comment: Edited to fix, but I'm not sure how to write it so that it will scan AF[B] for true and "written" as well as E[B] for the correct date condition.